# React - state doesnt update inside running function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have an async function that fetches some data from an endpoint. While waiting for the fetch call to return the user has the option to choose what should happen once the data has finsihed loading:

- redirect to the url associated with the fetched data get a
- notification that the loading process has finished

If I click on a button while fetching, a boolean state gets set from false to true. Once the API call returns, I check if the state is true or false. If it is false I redirect to another page, if it is set to true I send a notification. However, whenever I click the button, the state change doesnt get reflected inside the function and I always get redirected.

Here is a abstracted version of my code:

the function

```
 const data = await API.data.fetch(
  entities,
  Id
);

notify
  ? sendNotifcation({
      message: 'Data loaded successfully',
      }),
      duration: 5000,
      Icon: <FaCheckCircle size={35} className="text-green-d" />,
    })
  : redirectToPage(data._id);
```

The button

```
<button onClick={() => setNotify(true)}>Click me</button>
```

Does this have to do with the fact that rect state changes are handled asyncrinous? Or is this because I cant change the state for an already running function? Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Is the state supposed to be set to true every time the button is clicked or is the button supposed to simply switch the state, meaning, if it is true the state should be switched to false and if it were false it is must be switched to true?

Comment: It always sets it to true

Comment: Have you tried placing the fetch and notification code within useEffect with the appropriate dependencies?